# Allowing remote access to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have developed an asp.net web site and deployed it to IIS on my local pc. I am trying to set up my pc to be a temporary web server, but no matter what I do, I cannot access it from another machine. I just get a "Server not responding message". I have turned off the firewall and MS Security Essentials, but it is making no difference. All the other tips I have seen do not work.

Comment: Does http://127.0.0.1 work from your machine?

Comment: From the other machine, are you using a host name or ip address?

Comment: And you can ping the other machine?

Comment: Yes. I can ping the other machine

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is there are so many ways to go wrong here.

You are currently running IIS and not just testing in Cassini?
You can go to IIS Manager and see Default Web Site? 
You can do a Browse under Actions when Default Web Site is selected? 
You can get to your machine from another machine?
On your machine, can you browse to http://your-machine/your site?  (Not just http://localhost).

Comment: I am running IIS. I can see Default Web Site. I can get to my machine ofrom another machine on the same network, but not remotely. I can Browse under Actions when the default site is selected.

Comment: can you start smaller and try to just load a simple html page remotely to ensure that works?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that remote access and http access is turned off on your firewall. Are the other machines you've tested within your domain?

Comment: The other machines are not within my domain